# React Native 0.56 crashes at start up

Tags: react-native

After upgrading from version 0.44 -> 0.56 I keep getting this at the first render loop. Any ideas? (seems to be a internal react-native error). Google searching doesn't give me anything :-(

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.getItem')

This error is located at:
    in FlatList (at YellowBoxList.js:87)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in YellowBoxList (at YellowBox.js:104)
    in YellowBox (at AppContainer.js:93)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)

_checkProps
    FlatList.js:489:6
```

package.json - All packages are up to date (with `yarn upgrade --latest`). I'm using some *custom* packages to deal with other rn 0.56.0 issues. Such as `react-native-root-siblings` not being babel7 compatible.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "assert": "1.4.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "moment-range": "4.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-action-button": "2.8.4",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "2.4.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.3.0",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "3.5.0",
    "react-native-background-timer": "2.0.1",
    "react-native-branch": "2.3.2",
    "react-native-code-push": "5.4.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "0.13.0",
    "react-native-config": "0.11.5",
    "react-native-contacts-wrapper": "0.2.4",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "0.6.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "0.22.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "0.2.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^4.0.14",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.5",
    "react-native-fs": "2.10.14",
    "react-native-fullwidth-image": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-htmlview": "0.12.1",
    "react-native-i18n": "2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.20.3",
    "react-native-image-gallery": "2.1.5",
    "react-native-intercom": "11.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "0.5.2",
    "react-native-mail": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "6.0.0",
    "react-native-offline": "3.11.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "0.2.1",
    "react-native-picker": "4.3.7",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "0.14.52",
    "react-native-restart": "git+https://github.com/nmchr7/react-native-restart.git#master",
    "react-native-root-toast": "https://github.com/swapkids/react-native-root-toast.git#master",
    "react-native-segment-analytics": "0.1.14",
    "react-native-side-menu": "1.1.3",
    "react-native-simple-store": "1.3.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.1.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-tooltips": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "0.16.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "0.5.12",
    "replace-ext": "^1.0.0",
    "rn-viewpager": "1.2.9",
    "rrule": "2.2.9",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "validator": "10.4.0"
  }
```

Comment: You may have to upgrade the other dependencies. Try `yarn upgrade --latest` in the terminal

Comment: Didn't help. All packages are up to date. Still getting the error :-( Do you want to have a look at my package.json file?

Comment: Sure, add it to your question

Comment: done ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: That's a lot of packages, do you have more information of the error. Such as showing both the terminal error and emulator error.

Comment: same is happening to me after upgrading

Comment: My app suddenly stopped working on Android with same error, works fine in ios simulator.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by running

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

and then

> react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error, and for me the solution was to eliminate all the old babel-* devDependencies I had, remove node_modules, and run yarn to rebuild it.  The only babel-related packages I have left (now that it is working) are

    `"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0-beta.47",
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5"`

The last two are the ones that `react-native init` would put there for a new project, and the first I added because I use decorators.

Answer (score -1):

it is the 0.56 bug.
go for 0.54 and you wont have any problem
use this command:

```
react-native init --version="0.54.0" ProjectName
```

I had the same problem and it worked for me like a charm.
[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682163/error-code-500-on-react-native-0-56-for-android)

Comment: I'm having this in 0.58.3.