# error code: 500 on react native 0.56 for android

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native, mobile

[image: image 1]

my project is a new empty react native project.
everything is cool at the time of build, but on android device I face the red "error 500" screen every time.
I've tried this code:

```
yarn remove babel-preset-react-native
yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

no change so far!

I've tried to downgrade the react native to 55.4 - no change!
Cleaning the catch - no change!
Here is my App.js by the way:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

the index.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

and here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Windows 10 64bit
Webstorm

Comment: could you please post a photo of the error?

Comment: how is android is connected to windows cable or in same network

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fegT.png

Comment: i'm using usb cable - samsung galaxy grand-prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some issue with latest react native version.

Create the project with below command.

```
react-native init --version="0.54.0" ProjectName
```

It will surely work.