# The development server returned response error code: 500 - running React Native project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, bundle

I am trying to run my first application, but this error persists, I already typed the commands:
1.watchman watch-del-all (this is not recognized as an internal or external command)
2.rm -rf node_modules && npm install
3. reset

But nothing worked,

Someone knows how to solve this????? I will appreciate it!!!

[image]

Comment: Review my answer on below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853628/4611301

Answer (score 0):

For watchman, the command should be: "watchman watch-del-all". It looks like the command you used has a typo, as it is "watchman watche-del-all". Also, check that you have watchman globally installed.

From the traceback it looks like your issue is with the AccessibilityInfo module. Has this been correctly installed?

Would you be able to show more of your traceback?

Comment: Sorry I wrote it incorrectly in this description, but I typed it correctly in the console, I am going to check more of the trace-back to share it with you, thanks bro